# Entity model updating take to time when I click finishef

Tags: entity

I recently installed Windows Server 2019. I had a problem in updating the entity model. There is no problem until I press the finish key, but after pressing that key, it takes a long time and the update is not done correctly.

I didn't have this problem before with windows server 2016 and sqlserver 2016, but after installing windows server 2019 and sqlsetver 2019, I encountered a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the SQL Server Database compatibility to 110 and the problem was completely solved.

```sql
USE <database name>;  
GO  
SELECT compatibility_level  
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = <'database name'>;  
GO
ALTER DATABASE <database name>  
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 150;  
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the SQL Server Database compatibility to 110 and the problem was completely solved.

```sql
USE ;
GO
SELECT compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = <'database name'>;
GO ALTER DATABASE
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110;
GO
```